# base_margin or init_score for catboost regressor

Tags: offset, poisson, gbm, catboost, exposure

I would like to use a CatBoost regressor for insurance applications (Poisson objective). As I need to fix the exposure, how can I set the offset of log_exposure? When using xgboost I use "base_margin", while for lightgbm I use the "init_score" params. Is there an equivalent in CatBoost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking on the documentation, I found a viable solution. The fit method of both the `CatBoostRegressor` and `CatboostClassifier` provides a `baseline` and a `sample_weight` parameter that can be directly use to set an offset (for prior exposure) or a sample weight (for severity modeling).
Btw, the optimal approach is to create `Pool`s and providing there the specification of offset and weights:

```
freq_train_pool = Pool(data=freq_train_ds, label=claim_nmb_train.values,cat_features=xvars_cat,baseline=claim_model_offset_train.values)
freq_valid_pool = Pool(data=freq_valid_ds, label=claim_nmb_valid.values,cat_features=xvars_cat,baseline=claim_model_offset_valid.values)
freq_test_pool = Pool(data=freq_test_ds, label=claim_nmb_test.values,cat_features=xvars_cat,baseline=claim_model_offset_test.values)
```

Here the `data` parameters contain `pd.DataFrame` with the predictors only, the `label` one che actual number of claim, `cat_features` are character lists specifying the categorical terms and the `baseline` terms are the np.array of log exposure. It works.

Using Pools allows to provide evaluation sets in the fit method.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the "set_scale_and_bias(scale, bias)" method on your CatBoostRegressor model.
the bias parameter will set the offset of the model prediction results, while the scale parameter should be left as its default which is 1.
For your Insurance Poisson objective the bias should be set to log(exposure).

See more details here: [CatBoost documentation](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostregressor_set_scale_and_bias.html#python-reference_catboostregressor_set_scale_and_bias__examples)

Comment: It seems you can only set a constant value for the entire dataset, not each individual observation? Please correct me if I'm wrong.